# How do I create an object to move between two positions in unity, using C#, and why is my code not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I have this piece of code right here that should make the block object move between the `startPos` and `endPos` objects, but something is wrong about it and I don't know what.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (block.transform.position == startPos.transform.position)
    { 
        check = false; 
    }

    if(block.transform.position == endPos.transform.position)
    { 
        check = true;  
    }

    if (check == false)
    {
        block.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(block.transform.position, endPos.transform.position, .03f);
    }

    if (check == true)
    { 
        block.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(block.transform.position, startPos.transform.position, .03f);     
    }
}
```

At some point the block will reach `endPos`, and then on its way back to `startPos` it will stop, because the functions will be executed simultaneously. But how is this possible because my if's right there should not allow this to happen?

Comment: Why do you think both the lerp functions are being executed?

Comment: @Johnny Lerping between `startPos` and `endPos` results in a linear movement. Lerping between current position and destination results in a moving average, which looks smoother.

Comment: from what i know, i think i should Lerp from the block current position to the endPos at first, and the back to the startPos because i am using FixedUpdate and will actually transform the position of the object on every single frame, am i wrong ?

Comment: @Rotem I got it, removed comment ;) tnx

Comment: But i don't know how the functions actually end working simultaneously ?? I mean, how is that possible ??

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are using `FixedUpdate` here instead of `Update`? `FixedUpdate` is usually only used for `Physics` related stuff which doesn't seem to be the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should always be using

- [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) → called **every frame**

instead of

- [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) → called in certain **realtime intervals**

**except** you are dealing with `Physics` somehow (which doesn't seem to be the case here). Also see the [Update and FixedUpdate Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate)

---

The issue with [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is that it doesn't behave as you expect.

I guess you like that it starts fast and then becomes "smooth" ... but actually this might be your problem.

It **never** reaches the target position really. It just gets closer and closer and slower and slower ...

... until at some moment the [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) with a precision of `0.00001f` eventually becomes true.

So it might seem that it stopped but actually it might still be moving just really really slow.

---

For the following two alternatives you have to decide a bit what you want to control:

1. Option: The speed

   If you want to have a **linear velocity** for the object you should rather use

   ```
   // adjust via the Inspector
   [SerializeField] private float moveSpeedInUnityUnitPerSecond = 1f;

   // you should use Update here in general
   void Update()
   {
       if (block.transform.position == startPos.transform.position)
       { 
           check = false; 
       }
       // always use else in cases where only on condition can be
       // true at the same time anyway
       else if(block.transform.position == endPos.transform.position)
       { 
           check = true;  
       }

       block.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(block.transform.position, check ? startPos.transform.position : endPos.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
   }
   ```
2. Option: The duration
    If you rather want a **smooth movement** but **control the duration** it takes to reach the target you should use a `Lerp` but with a factor depending on the time like

   ```
   // adjust via the Inspector
   [SerializeField] private float moveDurationInSeconds = 1f;

   private float passedTime;

   // you should use Update here in general
   void Update()
   {
       // prevent overshooting
       passedTime += Mathf.Min(moveDurationInSeconds - passedTime, Time.deltaTime);

       if(passedTime >= moveDurationInSeconds)
       {
           check = !check;
           passedTime = 0;
       }

       var lerpFactor = passedTime / moveDurationInSeconds;
       // and now add ease-in and ease-out
       var smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

       var fromPosition = check ? endPos.transform.position : startPos.transform.position;
       var toPosition = check ? startPos.transform.position : endPos.transform.position;

       block.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, smoothedLerpFactor);
   }
   ```

   For this you could also use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which usually is a bit easier to interpret and maintain:

   ```
   // adjust via the Inspector
   [SerializeField] private float moveDurationInSeconds = 1f;

   // yes you see correctly one can directly use the Start
   // as a Coroutine
   private IEnumerator Start()
   {
       var fromPosition = startPos.transform.position;
       var toPosition = endPos.transform.position;

       // looks strange but as long as you yield somewhere inside
       // the loop it simply means repeat the sequence forever
       // just like the Update method
       while(true)
       {
           var passedTime = 0f;

           while(passedTime < moveDurationInSeconds)
           {
               var lerpFactor = passedTime / moveDurationInSeconds;
               // and now add ease-in and ease-out
               var smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

               block.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, smoothedLerpFactor);

               passedTime += Mathf.Min(moveDurationInSeconds - passedTime, Time.deltaTime);

               // reads like: "pause" here, render this frame and continue
               // from here in the next frame
               yield return null;
           }

           // once reached flip the positions
           var temp = fromPosition;
           fromPosition = toPosition;
           toPosition = temp;
       }
   }
   ```

   in both cases you could still add more flexibility and instead of simply using the `moveDurationInSeconds` use

   ```
   var fixedDuration = moveDurationInSeconds * Vector3.Distance(fromPosition, toPosition);
   ```

   this way the movement takes shorter if the positions are closer together and longer if they are further apart. This comes pretty close to the `Lerp` you used before regarding to the smoothness of motion but you can control very good how long the movement will take.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is a **percentage** of the distance between the first two arguments.  When you pass in `0.03f`, you're getting 3% **closer** to your end position but never actually getting **exactly** there (You can prove this by logging the block's position and the target's position and you'll see they're never perfectly equal).

Instead of checking if your block's position with the [== operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) (which works to an accuracy of 0.00001f) to the target position, you could simply check if it's **close enough** with [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html):

```
if(Vector3.Distance(block.transform.position, endPos.transform.position) < 0.1f) {
```

You can make your "close enough threshold" (`0.1f` in the example) a named variable for easy adjustment until it feels right.

Comment: this might be one reason but Unity already uses a `close enough` distance for [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) between two `Vector3`: `0.00001f` so it might take a while but the positions should be "matching" at one point

Answer (score 0):

For starters, Update() loops every frame. FixedUpdate() depends on the number of frames per second set in the time setting. So, put your code into Void Update() instead.

If you refer to [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) documentation, you may find a much better approach to your problem.

The script below should do the trick. The target variable should be set to the position of your end point. Speed is how fast your object should move.

Inside Update(), the step variable is used to determine how far the object should move based off its speed and the time elapsed since it last moved. Finally, the last line changes the position of the object and records the new position.

```
public Transform target;
public float speed;

void Update() {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
```